# Kubernetes: How do I know what node I'm on?

Tags: kubernetes

If I ssh into a Kubernetes node, how do I figure out the UUID for the node so I can query the master API for information specific to the node?

Tried this so far

```
root     13020  2.5  1.0 410112 41660 ?        Ssl  Jan25  26:04 /usr/bin/kubelet --logtostderr=true --v=0 --api_servers=http://10.32.140.181:8080 --address=0.0.0.0 --port=10250 --allow_privileged=false --maximum-dead-containers=1 --max-pods=14

[achang@p3dlwsbkn50d51 ~]$ curl -Gs http://localhost:10255/pods/
404 page not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of different IDs and names tied to kubernetes nodes, it depends on which you are looking for. If you want to query the API server for node info, you're most likely looking for the node name. The node name is often the same as the hostname, but if not the easiest way to find it is to query the kubelet for running pods, and see what node they're running on:

```
$ curl -Gs http://localhost:10255/pods/ | grep -o '"nodeName":"[^"]*"' | head -n 1
"nodeName":"e2e-test-stclair-minion-8o3b"
```

Other IDs can be found by querying the node spec:

```
$ curl -Gs http://localhost:10255/spec/ | grep -oE '(machine_|system_uu|boot_)id":.*'
machine_id": "",
system_uuid": "CB7FAAA0-3A53-5FE4-4285-D33D03FEBA6C",
boot_id": "8b89b8f5-5fbb-4cc0-82e4-7c57ec11f656",
```

Finally, `externalID` and `providerID` can be queried from the API server:

```
$ kubectl get nodes e2e-test-stclair-minion-8o3b -o=jsonpath="externalID:{.spec.externalID}; providerID:{.spec.providerID}"
```

EDIT:

If the above fails and you have access to the api server, you can just look for the node that matches the hostname of the desired node:

```
$ NODEHOST="your-host"
$ kubectl get nodes | grep "hostname=$NODEHOST"
```

Comment: Hey I tried your suggestion, but getting a 404 not found?

Comment: Can you post the exact command entered? Some of the paths are finicky about the trailing slash.

Comment: curl -Gs http://localhost:10255/pods/ -> is empty, I know I'm not running any pods but 404 not found is odd

Comment: Which version of kubernetes are you running? You should at least have a kube-proxy pod (in the kube-system namespace)

Comment: (added another option for getting the node name)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101719/discussion-between-tim-st-clair-and-amchang87).

Answer (score 14):

I found current kubernetes node (I check minikube, gke node pool) has file `/etc/machine-id`, which `cat /etc/machine-id` is unique for each kubernetes nodes and match with correspond `kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -r .items[].status.nodeInfo.machineID`.

because it does not need API invocation, I think this way is easier to combine with shell or container.

Comment: No idea why this answer doesn't have more votes. First, it actually solve the problem with no guess work. Second, it doesn't require networking or any special tools like kubectl or jq. I can map the file into my pod and I'm good to go.

Comment: A quick check with `minikube` reveals that Node's `metadata.uid` and `status.nodeInfo.machineID` have different values. Maybe `/etc/machine-id` is good enough to uniquely identify the node but it is not guaranteed to match node's `uid`.

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain the node name adding wide output option to kubectl :

`// List all pods in plain-text output format and includes additional information (such as node name).
$ kubectl get pods -o wide`

more options : https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/

Comment: the best answer

Answer (score 5):

Now you would better expose them during the deployment if you intended to use them later through env-variables.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME MY_POD_NAMESPACE;
          printenv MY_POD_IP MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
  restartPolicy: Never
```

refer to

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Answer (score 0):

kubelet is the entity running in each node and is like the "host agent" with which kube-api-server interacts to get the node specific information and also to do the  node specific tasks.

Kubelet has the information about the node name.  Typically, the node name is given with "--hostname-override" option when starting the kubelet.

So, the following command would give the node name if --hostname-override is set.

ps -eaf | grep kubelet | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "--hostname-override" | awk -F= ' { print $2 } '

Else, there must be kubelet APIs to give this information, but kubelet APIs are undocumented and hence it is better not to suggest them in stackoverflow