# How can a node (AWS EC2 Instance) read its Kubernetes labels?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kops

We are using `kops` to create our own `kubernetes` cluster in AWS EC2. We run some special processes on the EC2 instances and would like for them to have access to the `kubernetes` node labels, but I cannot find a way to access them from the instance.

How can I access the Kubernetes labels for the node the instance is hosting from the instance layer, outside of any containers, using standard Unix tools like `bash`, `curl`, and `sed`?

Comment: Are you running that special process directly on host or as a Daemonset via Kubernetes?

Comment: @VishalBiyani running directly on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running the process outside Kubernetes and directly on host, the first step would be get correct nodename (Which is same as hostname, but just to be sure) as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008011/kubernetes-how-do-i-know-what-node-im-on):

```
$ curl -Gs http://localhost:10255/pods/ | grep -o '"nodeName":"[^"]*"' | head -n 1
"nodeName":"e2e-test-stclair-minion-8o3b"
```

Then using Kubectl or Kubernetes API - whichever works, get labels of that node. I am assuming you have access to Kubeconfig and are using Kubectl:

```
kubectl get nodes gke-nodename-pool-87c8b616-549c -ojsonpath='{.metadata.labels}'
```

If you were running Daemonset - then you can use the downward API to get nodename and then query API to get labels for that domain. To get the nodename as a env variable inside pod:

```
env:
    - name: MY_NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    - name: MY_POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
```

If there is no Kubectl on nodes and if you don't want to run the process as daemonset - then running a small Go lang container as a daemonset - which gets nodename from ENV and then queries the labels from Kubernetes server and exposes on a nodeport which the host process can access seems the closet you can get!

Comment: No, the processes do not have access to `kubectl`.

Comment: Sorry - why the process can not access Kubectl?

Comment: We have not installed `kubectl` or set up a kube configuration on the nodes, and do not want to. That is why the process cannot use `kubectl`.

Comment: @OldPro Updated answer to handle case where you don't have Kubectl